# Dynamic Background Image Doesn't Work on Android 3.1 + PhoneGap

Tags: android, css, cordova, background-image

I'm creating an Android App using PhoneGap + JQM/HTML which displays products retrieved from a local JSON file based on user interactions.

**JSON:**

```
{
    "name" : "Product Name",
    "image" : "path/to/product.png"
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="products-display">
    <a href="#" class="products-link">Touch to Update Product</a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('body').delegate('.products-link', 'click', function(e){
    ...
    $(this).css('background','no-repeat url('+bgImage+')'); // bgImage = image node of JSON
    ...
});
```

The problem I'm running into is that the above works as expected on devices running Android 2.X; however on Android 3.0+ (in specific 3.1 on a Galaxy Tab 10.1") no background image is displayed.

Are resources handled differently on Android 3.X? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the path where picture is has the same casing as the path in the json data. Android paths are case-sensitive.